# c# EntityFramework version 6.1.3 NOT DELETE DETAIL

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I tried to follow the various guides and examples but I can not solve them. This is the error I get when I delete a row from the detail table linked to the master

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

CASE TEST 1:

```
using (var context = new clsDB.Entities())
{
    var DELETETEST= (from o in context.Tab_Master.Include("Tab_Details") where o.IdMaster == 472 select o).FirstOrDefault();
    if (DELETETEST!= null)
    {
        var detail = DELETETEST.Tab_Details.First();
        DELETETEST.Tab_Details.Remove(detail);

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

CASE TEST 2:

```
public class Docume : DbContext
{

    public Entities DocumeTest { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<Tab_Master>()
                    .HasKey(x => x.IdMaster);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Tab_Details>()
                    .HasKey(x => x.IdDetails);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Tab_Master>()
                    .HasMany(x => x.Tab_Details)
                    .WithRequired()
                    .HasForeignKey(x => x.IdTab_Master)
                    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    }
}
```

I checked the relationships END1 (cascade) and END2 (none)

I do not know what to do. 
Can you help me?

Comment: The first part of the question should be the description of your problem, then the error you get, and then what you have tried. Please, format your code too.

Comment: sorry, I created a connection to SQLSERVER through entityFramework 6. I have to manage the data of a Master table and a Detail table (child). I managed to view, edit but not to delete because I give the error The operation failed: ...... (described above) I have tried and I have seen that many have had the same problem. Here are some tests. I can not solve

Answer (score 0):

For Case1 you are just removing the foreign key relationship and not really deleting the `Tab_Details` from the DB. One way of fixing it would be to use:

```
context.Tab_Detail.Remove(detail);
```

instead of:

```
DELETETEST.Tab_Details.Remove(detail);
```

I'm not sure if this makes your Case2 irrelevant, but for now I would suggest just switching the one line.

If it is possible I would just get the `Tab_Detail` from the DB, e.g. using

```
var detail = (from d in context.Tab_Detail where d.IdTab_Master== 472 select o).FirstOrDefault();
if(detail != null)
{
    context.Tab_Detail.Remove(detail);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

assuming that a master has just one detail; otherwise if you know the `IdDetails` just use that for the select.

EDIT: change the last part of the Case2 (`OnModelCreating`) to

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Tab_Master>()
            .HasMany(x => x.Tab_Details)
            .WithRequired(x => x.IdTab_Master)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

The cascade delete should be set to true; meaning that if you delete the Master all Details need to be deleted (otherwise you'll also get the error you mentioned). For further reference take a look [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

Comment: tried. Identical error!  The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.